# My HP computer desktop turns black with only mouse cursor shown

Tags: windows, boot, reboot, desktop-computer, black-screen-of-death

I have an HP desktop which was working properly until the following happens:

It loaded normally as shown in the image showing the Windows logo with the loading dots.
The the screen turns black and only the mouse cursor is shown.

Sometimes if I wait for couple of hours it works fine but sometimes it never runs.

I tried to do the ctrl alt delete but never worked.

I tried enter the safe mode directly on startup by clicking F1 but nothing happened.

I have the data on disk D but the main government software is on C.

[image]

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: This happened to me but on Windows 7. It was because my smartphone was connected during boot. Disconnected it and reboot.

Comment: I dont have anything connected but my usb wireless and it was connected since 2 years.

Comment: If I were you, I'd probably reinstall the OS.

Comment: I have important data on disk I should recover. How can I do it first ?

Comment: You could boot the machine with a liveboot like Hiren's boot. Or you could take out the hard drive and connect it to another computer. If you don't have the experience or the willingness to do either of these the safest and simplest is the liveboot option.

Comment: I read below you can't enter your Bios. I've added an answer with extra detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think your greater issue here is your Bios not working.**

1. With your computer off, open it up and disconnect your hard drive.
2. On a second machine, connect only the power connectors to the hard
   drive and boot as normal. After it has booted connect the Sata.

This *should* enable you to see the hard drive on a 2nd windows environment and copy your data off. Or at the very least diagnose it,read it's smart attributes and run a chckdisk.

**Now that's out of the way, turn your attention to your Bios.**

1. On your motherboard you will find a small Battery. Carefully remove
   it and let the computer sit for about 15mins.
2. Place the battery again onto it's slot ( Be mindful of the right
   side up) and try to start the computer ( Yes without the hard drive
   ).

   Try to enter into your BIOS.
   If it still refuses to work, I would say you have a faulty motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible that your system disk has encountered a catastrophic error,
which might even be related to a hardware problem.

If you manage to boot, you should immediately check:

- S.M.A.R.T. data using a utility such as [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)
- Run `chkdsk`
- Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)

Depending on the results of these tests, you will need to decide if to replace
your disk.

If the disk behaves itself for some time, you might take a system image of
your disk using a product such as
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html)
and restore it on the new disk using its boot media.
This will save re-installing Windows from scratch.
For more information see the article
[How to Clone Hard Drive to SSD](https://www.backup-utility.com/clone/clone-hard-drive-to-ssd-4348.html).

If booting is not possible, then your options are much reduced:

- [Run a Startup Repair in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html)
  If this is only a boot problem, in the hope that the boot process will
  identify the existing Windows installation.
- Reinstall Windows from scratch.

If any of the above two methods works, your first action should be to
check the disk's S.M.A.R.T. data.

Comment: Well I cant manage to boot the system. I triedto press F1, F10 and F12 but I couldn't access to bios setup

Comment: This is much worse. I added two more options.

Answer (score 0):

I happened with me too. 
I did the following.
1, I turned off the laptop, took out the battery for around 1 hour and then put it back and hopefully it worked. 
Reinstalling the OS also works. hope this helps :) XOXO.